# Function printed twice

Tags: python

I'm not sure why my program is printing twice the answer key function I made. i tried adding the else statement down with the function but it kept having some errors the code works fine as how i made it but the function getting printed twice is bothering me.

```
import random

def main():
    guesses = []
    answerKey(guesses)
    brain(guesses)

def answerKey(guesses):
        print("Well done!")
        print("It took you %i guesses." % len(guesses))
        print("Here are your guesses: ")
        print(guesses)
        
def brain(guesses):
    secretNumber = random.randint(1, 100)
    playerNum = int(input("Enter a number between 1-100: "))
    guesses.append(playerNum)

    while playerNum != secretNumber:
        if playerNum > secretNumber:
            print("Too High!")
        else:
            print("Too Low!")
        playerNum = int(input("Enter a number between 1-100: "))
        guesses.append(playerNum)

    else:
        if playerNum == secretNumber:
            print(answerKey)

    
main()
```

Comment: could you maybe share an example of what would be printed? just give a copy-paste?

Comment: Well done!
It took you 0 guesses.
Here are your guesses: 
[]
Enter a number between 1-100: 33
Too Low!
Enter a number between 1-100: 55
Too High!
Enter a number between 1-100: 44
Too High!
Enter a number between 1-100: 41
Too Low!
Enter a number between 1-100: 42
<function answerKey at 0x000001656013B010>

Comment: You're calling `answerKey` before `brain`, or you've posted the wrong code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] which means example input, expected output, and actual output. Please [edit] the question; don't use comments because they don't support fancy formatting. For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the `answerKey(guesses)` from your `main` function, since it makes no sense to try to print the guesses before the user has made any.

In your `brain` function, change:

```
    else:
        if playerNum == secretNumber:
            print(answerKey)
```

to:

```
    answerKey(guesses)
```

You need to pass `guesses` to the `answerKey` function for it to be able to print the right output.  The `else` and `if` are both unnecessary because you haven't provided any way to exit the loop other than by getting the right answer.

Comment: after your most recent edit, yes, i agree with this

Comment: yeah that worked, im still practicing python so sorry for the question. thanks for the answer